# Cannot bind to parameter

Tags: azure, powerbi-desktop, kql

I'm creating a Power BI where I have a Kusto query from LogAnalytics with M query.
I'm following this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters#enabling-dynamic-m-query-parameters but cannot find the "Bind to parameter" option. It's just not showing up. I follow all the steps and nothing.

Has anyone found a similar problem and a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if this helps: [https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Dynamic-M-Query-Parameter-binding-not-shown/td-p/1457915](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Dynamic-M-Query-Parameter-binding-not-shown/td-p/1457915)

Comment: Are you using the Kusto/AzureDataConnection connector, or something else?